# How to figure out how far back a kitchen sink goes when the underside is not exposed?

Tags: sink, kitchen-sink

I'd like to replace my kitchen sink with one of the same dimensions. However, there is wood cabinetry concealing the entire underside of the sink. Perhaps it is standard to have the same sink wall thickness on the front and back, and thus I could just measure the inside of the basin and double the front wall thickness?

[image: Sink]

[image: Underside of sink]

Comment: The farm sinks like this that I have installed were at most 1” some only 1/2” beyond the opening of the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guideline is at most 4 inches from the lip of the counter to the front of the sink. This has to do with sink access for little people.

The back does not have to equal the front, but you need to keep space for your faucets of course. The issue is mostly the clearance required by the faucet, underneath. Usually that's another 3 inches or more, but read the specs.

The drain underneath can generally easily be moved to reach further back or front, or sideways as needed, to meet the above requirements.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. In hindsight I should have realized that there's room to spare behind the sink and thus an approximate measurement would be sufficient since there's plenty of room for error.

Comment: @Charlie good luck with the renos!